# netbeans database services empty

Tags: database, netbeans

I have just installed both netbeans 7.0.1 and 6.9.1.
When I click on the database node of the services tab I don't see anything in Netbenas 6.9.1, I can't even right click on it,  but everything is ok on 7.0.1.
Does anyone know how I can see databases in the 6.9.1.

I have already tried different versions and installed and uninstalled  both and installed one at the time.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help communicate the nature of this problem.

Comment: @Kev I also encountered the same simptomp here: http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/6219/databasenodeempty.jpg

OMG... how to solve it? I already did same updates but give me nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

netbeans 6.9.1 is compatible with jdk1.6.0. It may not work in jdk 1.7.So if you want to work database in netbeans 6.9 please degrade jdk to 1.6. Else upgrade netbeans to 7.0.1 to work with jdk 1.7.